# Flutter: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List'

Tags: android, flutter

I need to display the preview image in ListTile, I use Uint8List.
Here is my code in ListTile that gets Uint8List data:

```
                  ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 44,
                      minHeight: 44,
                      maxWidth: 64,
                      maxHeight: 64,
                    ),
                    child: Image.memory(loadAsset(paths[position].fileName)),
                  )
```

The very piece of code that gets Uint8List:

```
  loadAsset(name) async {
    Uint8List data = (await clientNextCloud.preview.getPreview(name, 10, 10))
        .buffer
        .asUint8List();
    setState(() {});
    return data;
  }
```

`await clientNextCloud.preview.getPreview(name, 10, 10)` - This piece, gets the Uint8List from package nextcloud dart.

I get the following error - `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List'`
Can someone tell me what the problem is?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `loadAsset` is an async method, which means it will return a `Future<T>`. You cannot change that since getPreview is also async.

To fix that, you need to adapt your UI to show something while the async method is not completed. You can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to achieve that.

Comment: `child: FutureBuilder(

future: listFiles(clientNextCloud),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return snapshot.data != null
                    ? listViewWidget(snapshot.data)
                    : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
          ),`
Yeah, i use FutureBuilder)

Comment: Thank you very much, thanks to you, I just added another line with preview to my model, and added the value to the list of objects, and then took the values from there, thank you very much for directing me correctly, not exactly what yt said, but you helped me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following approach -

```
loadAsset(paths[position].fileName).then((value) => {
               Image.memory(value),               
});
```

The loadAsset method is returning a Future value.

Comment: `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'` :(